# What is the purpose of this code peace like {...rest} here in the code(I'm not asking what the three dots spread notation in React Javascript do)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, notation, spread

**I'm not asking what the three dots spread notation in React Javascript do I know what they do ok?**
I learn ReactJs Javascript and read code and now I see this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dashboard-xzqhg?file=/src/views/account/AccountView/Profile.js:704-711)

You see the code piece:

[image]

**why in the code does the `<Card>` need the `...rest`, it does not do anything with it or am I missing something?**

What is the purpose to let the `Card` have the spread notation. `...rest` ? This happens on like 10 places in the code on all `<Card>` objects please advice? It does not use the values contain in the    spread notation or there are no values in the first place when all objects receiving the `...rest` is created.

Also the `className` props is inserted into the `<Card>` object but it's not used liks so: `className={clsx(classes.root, className)}` , is that really needed?

Comment: @I get that but why in the code does the `<Card>` need the `...rest`, it does not do anything with it or am I missing something

Comment: "*It does not use the values*" - are you sure the `Card` component doesn't have any props other than `className`? Unfortunately you haven't posted its code.

Comment: I included a CodeSandbox in my posts from the start did you miss that maybe or does the link not work?

Comment: when you use spread like { className, ...rest} , using layman explanation, you can say it's usually because only `className` is  "important" to the Component, the component don't care about the rest of the props, so it will **pass down** the rest of the props, e.g. in the form of `<div className={className} {...rest} />`. By separating `className` and `rest`, you do not pass the rest of the props down to the children. `rest` can consist of all the rest of the *unknown* props e.g. style, data-src, disable, editable etc etc

Comment: Material UI's `<Card>` component accepts many props other than `className`. For example, `raised`, `elevation`, `variant`, `children`. You can pass those props into `<Profile>`, and they will be passed along to the `<Card>`. The way they are passed along is `{...rest}`.

Comment: @NicholasTower, thanks I know how props work but why in this care are both {...rest} and className props inserted into the <Card>, it works ok if I remove them. I'm worried I missed something about Javascript React??

Comment: Because whoever wrote this code wants to pass a className through (which they calculate in `Profile`), and they also want to pass everything else through (which they don't make any modifications to). If you don't want both, then don't do both.

Comment: Thanks all, aha, but the Codesandbox is very well done code so I thought something advanced was going on heheh

Comment: "*I included a CodeSandbox in my posts from the start did you miss that*" - yes, it's easy to miss. Please [edit] your question to include all the relevant code in the post itself, screenshots and links are optional additions only.

Answer (score -1):

Just before some hours, i came across your question and had no idea about it. But i am taking a course and just by coincidence, he talked about `{...rest}`.

So how much i understood it is it is just a way to pass variable number of props to the component, i.e, when there is a posibility of unknown number of props.

If you have worked with python, i think `{...rest}` is just like `*args` in python which is used to take variable number of arguments.